# Transaction boundary is not properly set in JpaTransactionManager

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

Im using JPA with Hibernate implementation and using JpaTransactionManager to mange transactions.

Below is my application context file

```
<bean id="persistenceUnitManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" primary="true"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="persistenceUnitManager" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="infra_services" />
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"
    proxy-target-class="true" />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

I have defined my service class as below

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ComponentService {
```

I execute queries in dao layer as below

```
Query q = entityManager.createQuery(
            "SELECT cc.component FROM "
                    + this.typeParameterClass.getSimpleName()
                    + " cc WHERE cc.caseload.id = ? ").setParameter(1,
            caseloadId);

    Collection<Component> ddd =q.getResultList();
    for (Component c : ddd) {
        System.out.println(c.getComponentId());
        System.out.println(c.getComponentRelationships2());
    }
    return ddd;
```

I  started with select queries.  While executing the line `System.out.println(c.getComponentRelationships2());` getting `could not initialize proxy - no Session] with root cause` exception

Not sure why the session is not available here. Please help me on this.

Comment: Are your service in the same context as the one where you define <tx:annotation-driven /> ?

Comment: Service is not in same context. But I get this exception even in dao layer as soon as I execute the query

Comment: Are you sure that you have `<context:annotation-config/>` in your xml config file ?

Comment: Yes, I have it in my application context file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your service is not in the same context as the one where `<tx:annotation-driven />` then it's not working. Because it only look for bean in the same context. Extract from spring doc:

> @EnableTransactionManagement and  only looks for @Transactional on beans in the same application context they are defined in. This means that, if you put annotation driven configuration in a WebApplicationContext for a DispatcherServlet, it only checks for @Transactional beans in your controllers, and not your services. See Section 21.2, “The DispatcherServlet” for more information.

Comment: Thanks !!!, Also I added <context:annotation-config/> in my applciation context to resolve the issue